# Newline characters in Python displaying wrong results

Tags: python

I have data as below and the layout of this is

- Code: 4 characters
- Description: 255 characters (can vary)
- Class: 1 character

Due to the newline column in the description of PDF the Class column data is being pushed to next line a mentioned below.

How can we stream line so that the last column Class value is in the correct line and not pushed down?

Current converted text data from PDF:

```
CodeDescriptionClass
1007GOLF PUBLIC
A1002VIDEO,STREAM
D9999VIDEO IMAGE
E2232BELTS
P
```

Expected result:

```
1007GOLF PUBLICA
1002VIDEO,STREAMD
9999VIDEO IMAGEE
2232BELTSP
```

i am trying to convert the below pdf to text using below Code. First i am downloading to local and then reading the pdf and converting.
Code: Picking from Local after downloading

````
 pdfRead = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
 file1 = open('C:\xxx\xxx\mySrctxtfile.txt', 'w')
 for i in range(pdfRead.getNumPages()):
 page = pdfRead.getPage(i)
 pageContent = page.extractText()
 print(pageContent)
 file1.write(pageContent)  ```
````

Comment: For all lines except the first, you need to remove the first character and append it to the previous line. What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: if you have data in memory - ie. in list - then use `for`-loop to get first char from `line[i+1]` and add it to `line[i]`

Answer (score 1):

If you have all text in string then you could split to lines and use `for`-loop with `range(len(lines))` to get first char from `lines[i-1]` and add at the end of `lins[i]`

```
text = '''CodeDescriptionClass
1007GOLF PUBLIC
A1002VIDEO,STREAM
D9999VIDEO IMAGE
E2232BELTS
P'''

# split text to lines
lines = text.split('\n')

for i in range(2, len(lines)):
    # get first char in current line
    char = lines[i][0]

    # add it to the end of previous line
    lines[i-1] = lines[i-1] + char

    # remove first char from current line
    lines[i] = lines[i][1:]

# join lines to text
text = '\n'.join(lines)

print(text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may need also to remove last (empty) line when you  `join`

```
text = '\n'.join(lines[:-1])
```

Comment: it should be simple: read `text = open(filename).read()`; write `fh = open(filename, 'w')` `fh.write(text)` `fh.close()`